# Adding\Removing from ListView but not reflecting in UI

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have two `List<ColumnClass>`. one for left side listview and another for right side list view. these listviews are in a pop up box. I am modifying the List of both the Listviews and again assigning that to the Listview's ItemsSource. But this doesn't reflect in the UI immediatly. When I close the popup and open again it reflects the changes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the `List<T>` with `ObservableCollection<T>`, ObservableCollections will update your ListView whenever an Item is removed, If you are just modifing properties your `ColumnClass` make sure your `ColumnClass` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` this will allow the UI to update when a property changes.

Example:

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyColumns.Add(new ColumnClass { Name = "Column1" });
        MyColumns.Add(new ColumnClass { Name = "Column2" });
        MyColumns.Add(new ColumnClass { Name = "Column3" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ColumnClass> _myColumns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnClass>();
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnClass> MyColumns
    {
        get { return _myColumns; }
        set { _myColumns = value; }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WpfApplication8" Height="368" Width="486" Name="UI" >
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=MyColumns}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Model:

```
public class ColumnClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">The info.</param>
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).

Reason, List doesnot implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.